# SSRS why I can't use constants?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have a shared dataset with stored procedure which has optional parameter like this,

```
@OnlyUniqueEmail BIT = 0
```

and in end of I have predicate

```
WHERE 
        (@OnlyUniqueEmail = 0 OR  @OnlyUniqueEmail IS NULL )
    OR
        ((@OnlyUniqueEmail = 1 ) AND a.RowNumber = 1)
```

But when I try to give default to this parameter in **Shared Dataset Properties > Parameters**

I am not able to use expressions to provide false or true as  default value as you can see below...

[image]